# MPMoviePlayerController questions, best practices

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have any number of thumbnail images that, when tapped, will play a different video (fullscreen). I have never been clear on whether I should keep one MPMoviePlayerController object in my view controller and have it play whichever url according to the thumbnail that was tapped, or create a new MPMoviePlayerController each time. What is the best practice?

I am also having problems where tapping on different thumbs crashes the app, I believe because the MPMoviePlayerController tries to stream a video while it is already trying to stream. There seems to be no way to cancel a MPMoviePlayerController and clear out what it was doing, then start loading a new video.

Here's how I create it:

```
MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
self.player = moviePlayer;
[moviePlayer release];
```

Then to play a video I do this:

```
//would like to do something like this first - [self.player clear];
self.player.contentURL = someURL;
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[self.player prepareToPlay];
[self.player play];
```

Any advice is welcome... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are changing the video in an `MPMovieplayerController`,then you can remove the `mpmoviecontrollerplayer` view from super view using `removeFromSuperView` and again add it's subview to the super view initializing it with new URL.
No need to create new object every time.